# React Native: Nested (3 level) react navigator not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have an issue with React Native navigators.
I'm trying to create a layout using react-navigation. This layout involves stack navigators, bottom tab navigator. I'm 3 levels deep. The screens are structured like this:

- Stack.Navigator

  - Home (Tab.Navigator)

    - Home (Stack.Navigator) <-- Just focus this one, it's my problem, let me explain below.

      - Home (Screen)
      - Search (Screen)
      - Products (Screen)
    - Category (Screen)
    - Wishlist (Screen)
  - Login (Screen)
  - Setting (Screen)

Explain: If it's a screen instead of Stack.Navigator, everything's ok but I want Search and Products screen still have bottom tab so I need to put them here. Let me know if you need more clarification.

After all, application build successful but when I transit between screens, I get an error:
[image]
and can't go to other screens.

Overview my logic: MainStackNavigator include Home screen but Home screen at this time is a HomeTabNavigator, and HomeTabNavigator include Home screen is HomeStackNavigator, and HomeStackNavigator include Home screen and it exactly is a screen which I will show, is not HomeTabNavigator or HomeStackNavigator

This is my code:
[image]

Comment: Please post your code not images. Also explain when the error triggered? at which stage of the app? Post all related code so it can be evaluated well.

Comment: Better troubleshoot by removing some screens and checking then you can narrow down the issue, its really hard to pin point this error without seeing your code for all screens.

Comment: I think the problem is that your creating the navigators inside the components. You should create your navigators outside the component or else it will always create new instances and you don't want that

Comment: First of all, I thank everyone for taking the time to read through the post and give advice. I will try it. Thank you to everyone.

Comment: Hi @LuísMestre you're right. I have to move HomeTabNavigator to a new file, HomeStackNavigator to a new file and for now, it works well. You have my thanks.